# Rewite for in 0...n loop by map

Tags: swift, loops, enumeration

I have a swift code like below

```
var items: [Item] = []
for i in 0...20 {
    items.append( makeItem(atIndex: i) )
}
```

would it be possible to rewrite above like

```
var items: [Item] = [0...20].map {
   makeItem(atIndex: i)
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I need result of map, rewritten the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible, just don't wrap the range in an array, so use `(0...20)` instead of `[0...20]`

You can even pass the name of the function and you won't have to create a closure with a single call.

```
let items = (0...20).map(makeItem)
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax `[0...20]` Is an array containing **a single closed range** of `Int`, *not* an array of Int (which is what you would typically want to call `map()` on ), so what you really want is:

```
let integers = [
    0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 
    6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 
    12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 
    17 ,18, 19, 20]

integers.map{
   // your code here
}
```

*(My original answer missed this distinction, I have corrected it now. See other answers on how to convert a range into an array of `Int`)*

---

Both will execute the block within the brackets 21 times, one for each integer in the array.

But in contrast to the `for` loop, the `map()` function is expected to **return an array** of some type, where each element is obtained by transforming each of the elements in the original array (in this case, the integers `0` through `20`) into an instance of the resulting type. For example:

```
let textRepresentations: [String] = integers.map {
    return "\($0)"
}

// Now textRepresentations contains "0", "1", etc.
```

---

If your goal is to **assemble an array** out of objects created based on those 21 integers, `map()` gives you a more elegant solution than you would have done in a more "C-like" way, e.g.:

```
var textRepresentations: [String] = []
for i in 0 ... 20 {
     textRepresentations.append("\(i)")
}
```

But if you only need to execute some logic once for each of those integers, with no array left as a result, using `map()` (and discarding the result) will look awkward and confusing to people have to maintain that code (including your future self).

Additionally, a more "Swifty" alternative to the `for ... in` loop is `foreach` (which looks a bit more like `map()`, minus the returned array):

```
integers.foreach {
    // (use $0 instead of i)
}

...or, more verbosely:

integers.foreach { (element) in
    // (use `element`, of course)
}
```

Comment: I run [0 ... 20].map example of yours but it seem to execute only once

Comment: @Bigair I made a mistake in my answer. I'll fix it now

Comment: `return "\($0)"` the return keyword is redundant when you have a one liner inside your closure {`"\($0)"}`. Your map can be shortened to `map(String.init)`. Btw Swift is a type infered language. `let textRepresentations = integers.map(String.init)`

Comment: @LeoDabus yes, I know. Didn't want to make it too terse, on purpose.

Answer (score 0):

To get your exact syntax, you can create the extension:

```swift
extension Array where Element == ClosedRange<Int> {

    @discardableResult
    func map(_ f: @escaping(Int) -> Void) -> [Int]{

        var result : [Int] = []

        for i in 0 ..< self[0].count {
            result.append(i)
            f(i)
        }

        return result
    }
}
```

and call it like this:

```swift
let items = [0...50].map {
    print($0) // current index
}

print(items)
```

Note that items will be `[Int]`, this solves your question **before** your edits, when you just wanted to write a `for` loop like this:

```swift
[0...50].map {
    print($0) // current index
}
```